# Not able to install Pluggins on Jenkins on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am able to install the Jenkins on the Ubuntu 18.04 machine.
After installation i am able to launch the GUI successfully... When I try
to install any plugin it says:

> An error occurred during installation: No such plugin: `cloudbees-folder`

I tried restarting and tried installing on different Ubuntu server,but i am facing the same issue.

Can any body help me in resolving the issue:

1. Tried restarting the Jenkins.
2. Tried re-installing the Jenkins on fresh Ubuntu server.

Comment: Did you check the logs? You may try restarting the Jenkins application using command `service jenkins restart` and see if the issue persists.